# Get every information about the Reservation

Tags: c#, performance

I'm developing a plugin for Revit (a software to make 3D buildings).

The goal is simple to understand. When there is an intersection between a Wall and a Duct I create an object called *Reservation* at this location. I need to extract the Curve of the Ducts and the Faces of the Walls in order to calculate this intersection.

My algorithm is working fine and fast with a small building (3 Ducts, 10 Walls and 8 intersections) But when I want to launch it on a real project (around 10 000 Ducts) the code is way too slow due to many ForEach loops. Here is the sample which cause the issue:

```
foreach (Duct d in ducts)
            {
                Curve ductCurve = FindDuctCurve(d);
                curves.Add(ductCurve);

                foreach (Wall w in walls)
                {
                    wallFaces = FindWallFace(w);
                    foreach (Curve c in curves)
                    {
                        foreach (Face f in wallFaces)
                        {
                            foreach (KeyValuePair<XYZ, Wall> pair in FindInterWalls(c, f, walls))
                            {
                                Reservation.Res res = new Reservation.Res();
                                res.RoundCenter = new XYZ(Math.Round(pair.Key.X), Math.Round(pair.Key.Y), Math.Round(pair.Key.Z));
                                res.WallWidth = pair.Value.Width;
                                bool containsItemX = resList.Any(itemX => itemX.RoundCenter.DistanceTo(res.RoundCenter) < res.WallWidth + 1);

                                if (containsItemX == false)
                                {
                                    res.AssociatedWall = pair.Value;
                                    res.Radius = 1;
                                    res.AssociatedDuct = d;

                                    res.Center = pair.Key;
                                    resList.Add(res);
                                    model.Reservations.Add(new Reservation { ResList = resList });
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

The custom methods I'm using also contain loops. I wonder if a LINQ would be faster but I don't really know how to use it.

**In a nutshell** i want to get all the information about Reservations without loosing so much time stuck in so many foreach loops.

Here is my Reservation Class :

```
public sealed class Reservation
{

    public List<Res> ResList { get; set; }

    public class Res
    {
        public XYZ Center { get; set; }
        public XYZ RoundCenter { get; set; }
        public Duct AssociatedDuct { get; set; }
        public Wall AssociatedWall { get; set; }
        public double WallWidth { get; set; }
        public int Radius { get; set; }
    }

    public Reservation()
    {
        ResList = new List<Res>();

    }

}
```

[image]

A Curve is a right in the center of a Duct (each Duct contains one Curve). And a Face is a side of a Wall (each Wall contains 6 Faces)

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Please try to edit your title to describe what your code is doing and not what you want as a review. This make it easier for people to know what your code is about. Everyone here on Code Review is here for a review!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope I have understood this now.

Instead of iterating over all the `Duct` items and adding each iteration the related `Curve` to `curves` you should create another class like

```
public class DuctCurev
{
    public Duct TheDuct {get; private set; }
    public Curve TheCurve {get; private set; }
    public DuctCurve(Duct duct, Curve curve)
    {
        TheDuct = duct;
        TheCurve = curve;
    }
}
```

now we iterate once over all of the `Duct`'s and find the related `Curve` which we will add to a `List<DuctCurve>` like so

```
List<DuctCurve> ductCurves = new List<DuctCurve>();
foreach (Duct d in ducts)
{
    ductCurves.Add(d, FindDuctCurve(d));
}
```

then we need to adjust the remaining code to use the `ductCurves` and use the `!` operator instead of using `containsItemX == false` like so

```
foreach (Wall w in walls)
{
    wallFaces = FindWallFace(w);
    foreach (DuctCurve dc in ductCurves)
    {
        foreach (Face f in wallFaces)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<XYZ, Wall> pair in FindInterWalls(dc.Curve, f, walls))
            {
                Reservation.Res res = new Reservation.Res();
                res.RoundCenter = new XYZ(Math.Round(pair.Key.X), Math.Round(pair.Key.Y), Math.Round(pair.Key.Z));
                res.WallWidth = pair.Value.Width;
                bool containsItemX = resList.Any(itemX => itemX.RoundCenter.DistanceTo(res.RoundCenter) < res.WallWidth + 1);

                if (!containsItemX)
                {
                    res.AssociatedWall = pair.Value;
                    res.Radius = 1;
                    res.AssociatedDuct = dc.Duct;

                    res.Center = pair.Key;
                    resList.Add(res);
                    model.Reservations.Add(new Reservation { ResList = resList });
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The execution time is now 9 minutes ! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

You are calculating this for way too many objects and faces. Consider this algorithm (I'm not sure if it will work because I don't know how Revit stores objects but it might give you an idea).

- for each wall test if there is a duct within its boundig-box (is duct's b-box overlapping with wal's b-box?) - if not, you can already exclude it and save a lot of processing - working with b-boxes first should be much faster (was at least in my case as I had to solve similar task in a different 3d software)
- if they are overlapping then check which wall face's b-box overlapps with a duct's b-box
- now you can calculate the exact location like you do it - calc the ducts curves etc. do all the have work only with the objects that require that - they might be duct parts that don't overlapp with anything, you should look where you can skip processing time consuming operations